# Better way to select max values in multiple-column group?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, subquery

Simplified the following question I got from a coding challenge...

I have a table `grades` like:

```
year   sex   person   mark
2000   M     Mark     70
2010   F     Alyssa   23
2020   M     Robert   54
```

I want to select the people per year for both sexes that have the highest marks.

My Attempt:

```
   SELECT
        year,
        MAX(CASE
            WHEN sex = ‘F’ THEN person
            ELSE ‘’ END) AS person_f,
        MAX(CASE
            WHEN sex = ‘M’ THEN person
            ELSE ‘’ END) AS person_m
    FROM (
        SELECT
            year,
            sex,
            person,
            **mark
        FROM grades
        WHERE mark IN (
            SELECT MAX(mark) AS mark
            FROM grades
            GROUP BY year, sex)
        **) AS t
    WHERE x = 1
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY 1
```

I modified everything within the `** **` but the rest of the code was pre-populated. The code seemed right to me, but somehow only passed 2/4 test cases, and there were no tiebreaker records.

Also, I omitted the `WHERE x = 1` line, but the correct solution apparently needs that. (yes, `x` isn't a column in any table)

Is there a more elegant/efficient way to solve this?
Can't seem to figure it out, and it's really bugging me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this approach incorporates the `WHERE x = 1` clause as well.

```
   SELECT
        year,
        MAX(CASE
            WHEN sex = 'F' THEN person
            ELSE '' END) AS person_f,
        MAX(CASE
            WHEN sex = 'M' THEN person
            ELSE '' END) AS person_m
    FROM (
        SELECT
            year,
            sex,
            person,
            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY year, sex ORDER BY mark DESC) AS x
        FROM grades)
    WHERE x = 1
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use single quotes for Strings

The Problem of your query, is the subquery for your marks, you select a bunch of highest marks without associating them to the year, and gender

MySql allows you to IN clause with multiple columns.

```
   SELECT
        year,
        MAX(CASE
            WHEN sex = 'F' THEN person
            ELSE '' END) AS person_f,
        MAX(CASE
            WHEN sex = 'M' THEN person
            ELSE '' END) AS person_m
    FROM (
        SELECT
            year,
            sex,
            person,
            mark
        FROM grades
        WHERE (year,sex,mark) IN (
            SELECT year, sex,MAX(mark) AS mark
            FROM grades
            GROUP BY year, sex)
        ) AS t
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY 1
```

```
| year | person\_f | person\_m |
|-----:|:----------|:----------|
| 2000 |           | Mark      |
| 2010 | Alyssa    |           |
| 2020 |           | Robert    |
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tekB4XkI)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rank`. I added info to the table so you could see what happens in different scenarios including a tie.

```
select  year
       ,sex 
       ,person  
       ,mark
from   (
        select *
               ,rank() over(partition by year, sex order by mark desc) as rnk
        from   t
       ) t
where  rnk = 1
order  by year, sex
```

| year | sex | person | mark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | F | Alyssa | 23 |
| 2000 | M | Mark | 70 |
| 2000 | M | Danny | 70 |
| 2010 | F | Alma | 100 |
| 2010 | M | Dudu | 47 |
| 2020 | F | Noga | 98 |
| 2020 | M | Moshe | 56 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/COQyaDH3?hide=2)